# how is the css shader support as of 2014 & updates

Tags: html, css

I can't find this feature at caniuse.com and from research it seems no progress has been made since 2012. All articles pretty much are from 2012 as well.

I think this feature will help bring out the power in browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as indicated in [this article from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css-shaders.html), "CSS Shaders" as a whole are now known as "**CSS Filter Effects**."

The [W3C draft spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/), which at the time of this writing was last modified in November of 2013, defines the new features. Many of the new features are basically just existing SVG filter effects that will now be able to be used from CSS for arbitrary elements.

According to CanIUse, some of the filter effects [are available for newer versions of modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters). However, I suspect that this does not include the actual shader features, which are known as **CSS Custom Filters / CSS Custom Shaders**.

[This article from March 2013](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/03/Introduction-to-Custom-Filters-aka-CSS-Shaders) goes into an introduction to custom CSS filters/shaders, and links to more resources. It also mentions that custom filters have to be enabled directly from `about:flags` in Chrome.

So, basically, custom filters are still very much experimental, and very very few, if any, browsers will support it out of the box.

Comment: In the newest [W3C draft spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects/) (November 2014) Custom Filters were removed. Does that mean they're dead?